# How to call a function if *ngIf is true?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Here I have an `ion-input` which I want to hide only when `item.type==2` in the list of `items`

```
<ion-input type="text"></ion-input>

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div *ngIf="item.type == 2">
    <span>The End</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I go about this ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide it if *any* item has a type of 2? Why not write a property for it in the class and use that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. While parsing through items in `*ngFor` if any item is of type 2 , it should hide the `ion-input` dynamically. I tried keeping a property but did not figure how to implement dynamicity

Comment: Then I'd do `*ngIf="anyItemsAreTypeTwo"` and write a property getter; using `ngFor` for a side effect is not ideal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<ion-input type="text"></ion-input>

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div *ngIf="check(item)">
    <span>The End</span>
  </div>
</div>


export class YourCom{

   check(item){
       if(item.type == 2){

          callThatFunction();
       }

   }
}
```

This is a better practice anyway, that makes your `check` function testable, which is your business logic.

but don't forget that if you call a function that updates the view somehow, you're gonna get an error from change detection that says >"Expression updated after view is checked"

Comment: How should I go about avoiding that error ? I actually did get `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` EDIT : Hey I got your solution to work! Thanks

Comment: why dowbvote? ????

Comment: I did not downvote , Someone else did

Comment: How did you made it work (without the ExpressionChagedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError) ? Can you explain me ?

Comment: methods in template will be called on each change detection, so if your list of items are very long, you could potentially end up with poorly performing component.